# Swift: Run code when object is within an area

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm making a true or false game where the we have to determine if the logical expression is true or false. It's a one click game. If we click, the current true condition changes to false and vice versa. A series of logical expression will pop down the screen and when it reaches the zone, the current condition must equal to the logical expression to get a score. To verify the truth value, it checks the image of the truth value. I tried one case, where it is 'true and true' and the current condition is true, which is true. However, when it passes through the zone, the score did not increase. Where did I go wrong?

```
@IBAction func button_clicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if (truth_click == true) {
        truth_click = false
        self.truth_button.image = UIImage(named: "false_button")
    }
    else if (truth_click == false) {
        truth_click = true
        self.truth_button.image = UIImage(named: "true_button")
    }
}

func check_truth() {
    if (truth_click == true) {
        //when it reaches the zone
        if (left_truth.center.y > 330 ) {

            //if true and true
            if ((left_truth.image == UIImage(named: "true")) && (symbol.image == UIImage(named: "and")) && (right_truth.image == UIImage(named: "true"))) {
                self.score += 1

            }
            //if true and false

            //if false and true

            //if false and false

            self.score_label.text = String(self.score)
        }
    }

    if (truth_click == false) {
        //when it reaches the zone
        if (left_truth.center.y > 330 ) {

            //if true and false
            if ((left_truth.image == UIImage(named: "true")) && (symbol.image == UIImage(named: "and")) && (right_truth.image == UIImage(named: "false")))  {
                self.score += 1

            }
            //if true and true

            //if false and true

            //if false and false

            self.score_label.text = String(self.score)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your problem is testing `*_truth.image` against new instances of `UIImage(named:...)`.  UIImage is an object.  Instantiating a new UIImage creates a new object. Two objects with the same content are not equal ...without extra work.
[image]

Comment: What if I use a variable instead like (truth == "true"). Will that work?

Comment: Yes, that is a much better choice. You should also consider using boolean variables.

Comment: Hi Ringo. I've got rid of the variable problem. My problem now is when the logical expression reaches the area, the score increase but the logical expression suddenly disappears and respawned at the top. It was supposed to respawn after it gets until the bottom of the screen. Where did I go wrong? I'm really sceptical about the self.score_label.text = String(self.score) because if I remove it, the flow of the objects going down the screen goes smoothly but if it's there, the objects suddenly respawn while the score increase. Is it a control flow problem?

Comment: I am unable to answer this for you. Learn how to use Xcode's breakpoint debugging tool to stop code just before the failure and inspect local/global variables to find the values that you were not expecting.  Step code (or run it in short bursts) until something bad happens. Some will add log statements to print important variables at key times so that they can go back through the console log looking for the unexpected. Good luck.